# Resources, scopes, permissions and policies in Keycloak

Tags: permissions, keycloak

I want to create a fairly simple role-based access control system using Keycloak's authorization system. The system Keycloak is replacing allows us to create a "user", who is a member of one or more "groups". In this legacy system, a user is given "permission" to access each of about 250 "capabilities" either through group membership (where groups are assigned permissions) or a direct grant of a permission to the user.

I would like to map the legacy system to Keycloak authorizations.

It should be simple for me to map each "capability" in the existing system to a Keycloak resource and a set of Keycloak scopes. For example, a "viewAccount" capability would obviously map to an "account" resource and a "view" scope; and "viewTransaction" maps to a "transaction" resource... but is it best practice to create just one "view" scope, and use it across multiple resources (account, transaction, etc.)? Or should I create a "viewAccount" scope, a "viewTransaction" scope, etc.?

Similarly, I'm a little confused about permissions. For each practical combination of resource and scope, is it usual practice to create a permission? If there are multiple permissions matching a given resource/scope, what does Keycloak do? I'm guessing that the intention of Keycloak is to allow me to configure a matrix of permissions against resources and scopes, so for example I could have permission to access "accounts" and permission for "view" scope, so therefore I would have permission to view accounts?

I ask because the result of all this seems to be that my old "viewAccount" capability ends up creating an "Account" resource, with "View" scope, and a "viewAccount" permission, which seems to get me back where I was. Which is fine, if it's correct.

Finally, obviously I need a set of policies that determine if viewAccount should be applied. But am I right that this means I need a policy for each of the legacy groups that a user could belong to? For example, if I have a "help desk" role, then I need a "help desk membership" policy, which I could then add to the "viewAccount" permission. Is this correct?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: no. in the end I just wrote a new microservice to map our old system. I still think Keycloak authorizations are the way to go but I couldn't wait for the documentation (or my knowledge) to catch up. We do use Keycloak in production as an IDP.

Comment: we're also just about to give it a try... did u ever look at IDP from WSO2?

Comment: Nah, we are trying out the red hat train (wildfly micro) so we through we'd keep it in the family. I've been meaning to check out the wso2 stuff.

Comment: Keycloak looks like a pretty mature and very capable system, but what it can really do remains a mystery as there seems to be so many questions and so little answers. I'm literally asking myself all the questions in your post and unable to find any answers. Why are there no good tutorials out there? Does no one actually use this stuff? Or does no one bother to write about it?

Comment: Keycloak is working great for us in production (so far) with the exception of authorization, which was really difficult to relate to my actual problems. But I agree, there is lots of documentation about how Keycloak does OIDC, but also a pervasive assumption that we know OAuth and OIDC. It's hard to relate Keycloak to application problems if you don't already know OIDC, but for me Keycloak was the introduction to OIDC, which is a bit of a catch 22. (Picketlink/Picketbox was even worse!). I found that downloading it and just playing with it, was best.

Comment: agree on these comments, keycloak documentation and uses cases sucks

Comment: Keycloak devs, take note of this question! Your documentation is pretty good, but it needs more tutorials addressing the questions raised here. You might also consider migrating away from the old school mailing list to something a bit more user friendly like a forum or just Stackoverflow.

Comment: Late answer but all your assumptions are basically correct. As to what is the best practice, I think it is hard to say since the capability is very new. Not sure if even kc devs know what best practices are at this point.

Comment: @DoctorEval thank you for taking the time to read my answer :)

Comment: @Andy no worries, TBH I only got to skim it but it's an awesome answer and am looking forward to walking through it in detail.

Comment: I found this really useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K77Pvv-ouU

Comment: Hello everyone! recently was published the first book of keycloak! https://www.keycloak.org/2021/06/book.adoc.html

Comment: @StijndeWitt I am asking the same question in 2022! Actually I found two critical bugs in keycloaks authz script, leaving it completely unusable (one is a syntax error!). Not even the examples from the docs are working. Nobody could have ever used it. Not even the devs themselves.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Full transparency—I am by no means a Keycloak, [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), or [OIDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Connect_(OIDC)) expert and what I know is mostly from reading the docs, books, good ol' YouTube and playing around with the tool.

This post will be comprised of two parts:

1. I'll attempt to answer all your questions to the best of my ability
2. I'll show you all how you can play around with policies/scopes/permissions in Keycloak without needing to deploy a separate app in order to better understand some of the core concepts in this thread. Do note though that this is mostly meant to get you all started. I'm using `Keycloak 8.0.0`.

## Part I

Some terminology before we get started:

- In Keycloak, you can create two types of permissions: [Resource-Based](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_create_resource) and [Scope-Based](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_create_scope).
- Simply put, for `Resource-Based` permissions, you apply it directly to your resource
- For `Scoped-Based` permission, you apply it to your scope(s) or scope(s) **and** resource.

> is it best practice to create just one "view" scope, and use it across multiple resources (account, transaction, etc.)? Or should I create a "viewAccount" scope, a "viewTransaction" scope, etc.?

Scopes represent a set of rights at a protected resource. In your case, you have two resources: `account` and `transaction`, so I would lean towards the second approach.

In the long run, having a global `view` scope associated with all your resources (e.g., `account`, `transaction`, `customer`, `settlement`...) makes authorization difficult to both manage and adapt to security requirement changes.

Here are a few examples that you can check out to get a feel for design

- [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes)
- [Box API](https://developer.box.com/en/guides/api-calls/permissions-and-errors/scopes/)
- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference)

Do note though - I am not claiming that you shouldn't share scopes across resources. Matter of fact, `Keycloak` allows this for resources with the same `type`. You could for instance need both `viewAccount` and `viewTransaction` scope to read a transaction under a given account (after all you might need access to the account to view transactions). Your requirements and standards will heavily influence your design.

> For each practical combination of resource and scope, is it usual practice to create a permission?

Apologies, I don't fully understand the question so I'll be a bit broad. In order to grant/deny access to a `resource`, you need to:

- Define your [policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_policy_overview)
- Define your [permissions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_overview)
- Apply your policies to your permissions
- Associate your permissions to a `scope` or `resource` (or both)

for policy enforcement to take effect. See [Authorization Process](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#the-authorization-process).

How you go about setting all this up is entirely up to you. You could for instance:

- Define individual policies, and tie each policy under the appropriate permission.
- Better yet, define individual policies, then group all your related policies under an `aggregated` policy (a policy of policies) and then associate that aggregated policy with the `scope-based` permission. You could have that `scoped-based` permission apply to both the resource and all its associated scope.
- Or, you could further break apart your permissions by leveraging the two separate types. You could create permissions solely for your resources via the `resource-based` permission type, and separately associate other permissions solely with a scope via the `scope-based` permission type.

You have options.

> If there are multiple permissions matching a given resource/scope, what does Keycloak do?

This depends on

1. The resource server's  `Decision Strategy`
2. Each permission's `Decision Strategy`
3. Each policy's `Logic` value.

The `Logic` value is similar with Java's `!` operator. It can either be `Positive` or `Negative`. When the `Logic` is `Positive`, the policy's final evaluation remains unchanged. When its `Negative`, the final result is negated (e.g. if a policy evaluates to false and its `Logic` is `Negative`, then it will be `true`). To keep things simple, let's assume that the `Logic` is always set to `Positive`.

The `Decision Strategy` is what we really want to tackle. The `Decision Strategy` can either be `Unanimous` or `Affirmative`. From the docs,

> **Decision Strategy**

> This configurations changes how the policy evaluation engine decides whether or not a resource or scope should be granted based on the outcome from all evaluated permissions. **Affirmative** means that at least one permission must evaluate to a positive decision in order grant access to a resource and its scopes. **Unanimous** means that all permissions must evaluate to a positive decision in order for the final decision to be also positive. As an example, if two permissions for a same resource or scope are in conflict (one of them is granting access and the other is denying access), the permission to the resource or scope will be granted if the chosen strategy is Affirmative. Otherwise, a single deny from any permission will also deny access to the resource or scope.

Let's use an example to better understand the above. Suppose you have a resource with two permissions and someone is trying to access that resource (remember, the `Logic` is `Positive` for all policies). Now:

1. `Permission One` has a `Decision Strategy` set to `Affirmative`. It also has 3 policies where they each evaluate to:

- `true`
- `false`
- `false`

  Since one of the policies is set to `true`, `Permission One` is set to `true` (Affirmative - only 1 needs to be `true`).

2. `Permission Two` has a `Decision Strategy` set to `Unanimous` with two policies:

- `true`
- `false`

  In this case `Permission Two` is `false` since one policy is false (Unanimous - they all need to be `true`).

3. Now comes the **final** evaluation. If the resource server's `Decision Strategy` is set to `Affirmative`, access to that resource would be granted because `Permission One` is `true`. If on the other hand, the resource server's `Decision Strategy` is set to `Unanimous`, access would be denied.

See:

- [Resource Server Settings](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#resource_server_settings)
- [Managing Permissions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_overview)

We'll keep revisiting this. I explain how to set the resource sever's `Decision Strategy`  in Part II.

> so for example I could have permission to access "accounts" and permission for "view" scope, so therefore I would have permission to view accounts?

The short answer is yes. Now, let's expand on this a bit :)

If you have the following scenario:

1. Resource server's `Decision Strategy` set to `Unanimous` or `Affirmative`
2. Permission to access the `account/{id}` resource is `true`
3. Permission to access the `view` scope is `true`

You will be granted access to view the account.

- `true` + `true` is equal to `true` under the `Affirmative` or `Unanimous` `Decision Strategy`.

Now if you have this

1. Resource server's `Decision Strategy` set to `Affirmative`
2. Permission to access the `account/{id}` resource is `true`
3. Permission to access the `view` scope is `false`

You will *also* be granted access to view the account.

- `true` + `false` is `true` under the `Affirmative` strategy.

The point here is that access to a given resource also depends on your setup so be careful as you may not want the second scenario.

> But am I right that this means I need a policy for each of the legacy groups that a user could belong to?

I'm not sure how Keycloak behaved two years ago, but you can specify a [Group-Based policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_group) and simply add all your groups under that policy. You certainly do not need to create one policy per group.

> For example, if I have a "help desk" role, then I need a "help desk membership" policy, which I could then add to the "viewAccount" permission. Is this correct?

Pretty much. There are many ways you can set this up. For instance, you can:

1. Create your resource (e.g. `/account/{id}`) and associate it with the `account:view` scope.
2. create a [Role-Based Policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_rbac) and add the `helpdesk` role under that policy
3. Create a `Scope-Based` permission called `viewAccount` and tie it with `scope`, `resource` and `policy`

We'll set up something similar in Part II.

## Part II

Keycloak has a neat little tool which allows you test all your policies. Better yet, you actually do not need to spin up another application server and deploy a separate app for this to work.

Here's the scenario that we'll set up:

1. We'll create a new realm called `stackoverflow-demo`
2. We'll create a `bank-api` client under that realm
3. We will define a resource called `/account/{id}` for that client
4. The `account/{id}` will have the `account:view` scope
5. We'll create a user called `bob` under the new realm
6. We'll also create three roles: `bank_teller`, `account_owner` and `user`

- We will not associate `bob` with any roles. This is not needed right now.

7. We'll set up the following two `Role-Based` policies:

   - `bank_teller` and `account_owner` have access to the `/account/{id}` resource
   - `account_owner` has access to the `account:view` scope
   - `user` does not have access to the resource or scope
8. We'll play around with the `Evaluate` tool to see how access can be granted or
   denied.

Do forgive me, this example is unrealistic but I'm not familiar with the banking sector :)

### Keycloak setup

#### Download and run Keycloak

```
cd tmp
wget https://downloads.jboss.org/keycloak/8.0.0/keycloak-8.0.0.zip
unzip keycloak-8.0.0.zip
cd keycloak-8.0.0/bin
./standalone.sh
```

#### Create initial admin user

1. Go to  `http://localhost:8080/auth`
2. Click on the `Administration Console` link
3. Create the admin user and login

Visit [Getting Started](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/) for more information. For our purposes, the above is enough.

### Setting up the stage

#### Create a new realm

1. Hover your mouse around the `master` realm and click on the `Add Realm` button.
2. Enter `stackoverflow-demo` as the name.
3. Click on `Create`.
4. The top left should now say `stackoverflow-demo` instead of the `master` realm.

See [Creating a New Realm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html#_create-realm)

#### Create a new user

1. Click on the `Users` link on the left
2. Click on the `Add User` button
3. Enter the `username` (e.g., `bob`)
4. Ensure that `User Enabled` is turned on
5. Click `Save`

See [Creating a New User](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html#_create-new-user)

#### Create new roles

1. Click on the `Roles` link
2. Click on `Add Role`
3. Add the following roles: `bank_teller`, `account_owner` and `user`

Again, do **not** associate your user with the roles. For our purposes, this is not needed.

See [Roles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#roles)

#### Create a client

1. Click on the `Clients` link
2. Click on `Create`
3. Enter `bank-api` for the `Client ID`
4. For the `Root URL` enter `http://127.0.0.1:8080/bank-api`
5. Click on `Save`
6. Ensure that `Client Protocol` is `openid-connect`
7. Change the `Access Type` to `confidential`
8. Change `Authorization Enabled` to `On`
9. Scroll down and hit `Save`. A new `Authorization` tab should appear at the top.
10. Click on the `Authorization` tab and then `Settings`
11. Ensure that the `Decision Strategy` is set to `Unanimous`

- This is the resource server's `Decision Strategy`

See:

- [Creating a Client Application](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_resource_server_create_client)
- [Enabling Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_resource_server_enable_authorization)

#### Create Custom Scopes

1. Click on the `Authorization` tab
2. Click on `Authorization Scopes` > `Create` to bring up `Add Scope` page
3. Enter `account:view` in the name and hit enter.

#### Create "View Account Resource"

1. Click on `Authorization` link above
2. Click on `Resources`
3. Click on `Create`
4. Enter `View Account Resource` for both the `Name` and `Display name`
5. Enter `account/{id}` for the `URI`
6. Enter `account:view` in the `Scopes` textbox
7. Click `Save`

See [Creating Resources](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_resource_create)

#### Create your policies

1. Again under the `Authorization` tab, click on `Policies`
2. Select `Role` from the the `Create Policy` dropdown
3. In the `Name` section, type `Only Bank Teller and Account Owner Policy`
4. Under `Realm Roles` select both the `bank_teller` and `account_owner` role
5. Ensure that `Logic` is set to `Positive`
6. Click `Save`
7. Click on the `Policies` link
8. Select `Role` again from the `Create Policy` dropdown.
9. This time use `Only Account Owner Policy` for the `Name`
10. Under `Realm Roles` select `account_owner`
11. Ensure that `Logic` is set to `Positive`
12. Click `Save`
13. Click on the `Policies` link at the top, you should now see your newly created policies.

See [Role-Based Policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_rbac)

Do note that Keycloak has much more powerful policies. See [Managing Policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_overview)

#### Create Resource-Based Permission

1. Again under the `Authorization` tab, click on `Permissions`
2. Select `Resource-Based`
3. Type `View Account Resource Permission` for the `Name`
4. Under `Resources` select `View Account Resource`
5. Under `Apply Policy` select `Only Bank Teller and Account Owner Policy`
6. Ensure that the `Decision Strategy` is set to `Unanimous`
7. Click `Save`

See [Create Resource-Based Permissions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_create_resource)

*Phew...*

#### Evaluating the Resource-Based permission

1. Again under the `Authorization` tab, select `Evaluate`
2. Under `User` enter `bob`
3. Under `Roles` select `user`

   - This is where we will associate our user with our created roles.
4. Under `Resources` select `View Account Resource` and click `Add`
5. Click on Evaluate.
6. Expand the `View Account Resource with scopes [account:view]` to see the results and you should see `DENY`.

   [image]
7. This makes sense because we only allow two roles access to that resource via the `Only Bank Teller and Account Owner Policy`. Let's test this to make sure this is true!
8. Click on the `Back` link right above the evaluation result
9. Change bob's role to `account_owner` and click on `Evaluate`. You should now see the result as `PERMIT`. Same deal if you go back and change the role to `bank_teller`

See [Evaluating and Testing Policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_evaluation_overview)

#### Create Scope-Based Permission

1. Go back to the `Permissions` section
2. Select `Scope-Based` this time under the `Create Permission` dropdown.
3. Under `Name`, enter `View Account Scope Permission`
4. Under `Scopes`, enter `account:view`
5. Under `Apply Policy`, enter `Only Account Owner Policy`
6. Ensure that the `Decision Strategy` is set to `Unanimous`
7. Click `Save`

See [Creating Scope-Based Permissions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_create_scope)

Second test run

#### Evaluating our new changes

1. Go back to the `Authorization` section
2. Click on `Evaluate`
3. User should be `bob`
4. Roles should be `bank_teller`
5. Resources should be `View Account Resource` and click `Add`
6. Click on `Evaluate` and we should get `DENY`.

   - Again this should come as no surprise as the `bank_teller` has access to the `resource` but not the `scope`. Here one permission evaluates to true, and the other to false. Given that the resource server's `Decision Strategy` is set to `Unanimous`, the final decision is `DENY`.
7. Click on `Settings` under the `Authorization` tab, and change the `Decision Strategy` to `Affirmative` and go back to steps 1-6 again. This time, the final result should be `PERMIT` (one permission is true, so final decision is true).
8. For the sake of completeness, turn the resource server's `Decision Strategy` back to `Unanimous`. Again, go back to steps 1 through 6 but this time, set the role as `account_owner`.  This time, the final result is again `PERMIT` which makes sense, given that the `account_owner` has access to both the `resource` and `scope`.

Comment: Thank you, @Andy, for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 38):

I know I am bit late to the party, but let me try to explain as much as I can.

In Keycloak, we have terms like:

**Resource**: object which users will be accessing or performing the action on

**Auth scopes**: Actions that users can perform on the specific object

**Policies**: Policy

**Permission**: Mapping actually occur here

**If you don't want to follow manual way you can export this JSON and all the users, resources, permissions will be auto-set bu keycloak**

[JSON configuration file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B1vG_fmPLuDFJUP5cyj_IY-VHjSqsPyA/view?usp=sharing)

Now let's see a scenario where:

[image]

Now we have few resources like:

1. Account
2. Bot
3. Report

We want to implement the scenario where only specific user can performe specific actions.

### Setting up the Keycloak

**Create a new realm**

1. Click on the **Add Realm** button.

   [image]
2. Enter **test-v1** as the name.
3. Click on Create.

   [image]

### Create new roles

1. Click on the **Roles**
2. Click on **Add Role**
3. Create the roles "admin", "agent" & "super_admin"

   [image]

### Create a client

- Click on the **Clients** tab
- Enter **app-client** in Client ID textbox
- Click on <kbd>Save</kbd>
- Select and choose client again to configure other settings
- Verify the client Protocol is **openid-connect**
- Set Access Type to confidential
- Set Authorization Enabled to On
- Click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button at last.
- A new **Authorization** tab will appear at the top.
- Select on the Authorization tab and then Settings

  Check that the Decision Strategy is set to **Unanimous**. This is the **resource server** strategy

  [image]

### Create Custom Auth Scopes

Go the **Authorization** tab
Select **Authorization Scopes** → and click on <kbd>Create</kbd>
Enter **scopes:create** & **scopes:view** in the text and save values.

[image]

### Create Resource

- Go to **Resources** tab now → and click on <kbd>Create</kbd>
- Enter one by one and create the following resources **res:account** & **res:bot** & **res:report**
- For all resources in scope text, select both scopes that we created early **scopes:create** & **scopes:view**
- Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

  [image]

### Create policies

- Again inside the Authorization tab, select on **Policies**
- Click on the **Create Policy** dropdown and select the **Role**
- In the Name textbox, **Admin**
- In Realm Roles select role **Admin**
- Check Logic is set to Positive
- Click <kbd>Save</kbd>, and do the same for "Agent" & "Super_admin"

  [image]
- Again inside the Authorization tab, select on **Policies**
- Click on the **Create Policy** dropdown and select the **Aggregated**
- In the Name textbox, **Admin or Super_admin or Agent**
- In Realm Roles select role **Admin & Super_admin & Agent**
- Check Logic is set to **Affirmative**
- Click Save

  [image]

### Create permission

- Again inside the Authorization tab, select on **Permission**
- Click on the **Create Permissions** dropdown and select the **Scope-Based**
- In the Name textbox, **account-create**
- In resource box, select the "resource res:account"
- In scopes select, **scopes:create**
- Apply policy **Admin**
- We have to set permission same way for all the resources as per requirement

  [image]

### Create user

- Inside the user tab create one **test** user
  We will not assign any roles, scopes, or group to it for testing

### Let's Evaluate

- Again inside the Authorization tab, select on **Evaluate**
- Select the client we created, **app-client**
- In user select the created user, **test**
- In roles select the created user, **admin**
- Resource value, **res:account**
- Click on the **Add** button
- Click on the **Evaluate** button

  [image]

  You will see grant is **permitted** as **Admin** role has access to do operations **create** and **view** on resource **account**.

### Let's Evaluate Again

- Again inside the Authorization tab, select on **Evaluate**
- Select the client we created, **app-client**
- In user select the created user, **test**
- In roles select the created user, **admin**
- Resource value, **res:report**
- Scopes value, **scopes:create**
- Click on **Add** button
- Click on **Evaluate** button

  [image]

You will see grant is **Deny** as only **Super_Admin** role has access to do operations **create** on resource **report**.

Comment: thank you so much it helps ! i have a question if u don't mind can use an API that i will add it to the code source of keycloak to connec my app to it or i need to just use identify provider

Comment: glad to hear that, sorry didn't get your question. however please feel free to add more in details. still trying to answer : your application will connect to keycloak over JSON file config something like : https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/keycloak.json this whole example is in Node js and it's very nice you can check that out once

Comment: hi @HarshManvar, is it applied for microservice? I have tried your suggestion with two pages (A & B). A&B are two services, using keycloak for authentication along with OAuth. I added them in the `Validate Redirect URLs` but seems it does not work

Answer (score 11):

I was looking to enforce authorization via pure HTTP methods, without using the adapter as Lua did not have an adapter. Hope this answer helps people looking for non-adapter based method.

If you are looking for the adapter the [quick start guide](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts) is the best place to start. Especially the [spring boot authz example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-springboot).

For pure HTTP based implementation:

**Step 1:**

Define the policies and permission in the [Keycloak Admin UI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_resource_overview)

**Step 2**

Have an internal mapping of which HTTP paths belong to which resources and the required scopes for each path. This can be also saved in the [configuration file](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter). When a particular route is invoked, call the Keycloak token endpoint to validate the claims of the access token.

```js
{
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "user-managed-access" : {},
    "enforcement-mode" : "ENFORCING"
    "paths": [
      {
        "path" : "/someUri/*",
        "methods" : [
          {
            "method": "GET",
            "scopes" : ["urn:app.com:scopes:view"]
          },
          {
            "method": "POST",
            "scopes" : ["urn:app.com:scopes:create"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are using an adapter and does not specify the path or resource, the adapter will internally search for the paths and resources [from Keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f70af83fb628da80dc54968248af85b9ac25a45f/authz/client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/client/resource/ProtectedResource.java#L220).

**Step 3:**

Use the token endpoint to [get or evaluate](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_obtaining_permissions) the permissions. You can use `response_mode` parameter to either obtain the final decision (whether to provide access) or retrieve the entire permissions.

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
  --data "permission=Resource A#Scope A"
```

If the authorization request does not map to any permission, a `403` HTTP status code is returned instead.

Answer (score 3):

A working solution with resources, scopes and permissions can be found here
[keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example)

Just run already configured Keycloak using docker-compose using [Quick Start guide](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example#quick-start).

Other useful examples in the project

- Custom login without using Keycloak login page.
- Stateless Node.js server without using a session. Keycloak token is stored using cookies.
- A centralized middleware to check permissions. Routes are not described explicitly can't be accessed.
- Configuration without keycloak.json. It can be used to having configuration for multiple environments. For example — DEV, QA.
- Examples of using Keycloak REST API to create users, roles and custom attributes.