# Role model transfer to keycloak

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

The legacy project has the following role model:

User -> [Role1, Role2,...]

Role -> [Permission1, Permissions 2,...]

Permissions can be repeated in different roles

At the moment, basic auth is configured in the project. We are going to switch to OAuth 2.0 and consider Keycloak as Identity Provider. I have looked into the possibility of migrating the current role model to Keycloak, but have not found any information on how to do this. There was an article from more or less similar:

[Resources, scopes, permissions and policies in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak)

However, it uses a slightly different model.

I have a question: how can I represent the current structure in terms of Keycloak

If it is possible, is it possible to load data about users, their roles and permissions using realm import