# Keycloak confidential client authorization code flow without providing client_secret

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm implementing authorization code flow using Keycloak confidential client. When using code to exchange for tokens, Keycloak requires `client_secret` in payloads, otherwise, Keycloak returns error: `invalid client or invalid client credentials`.

Is it possible to omit `client_secret` from exchanging token's payload? I searched for PKCE but it seems like PCKE is only used for public clients.

Comment: The whole point of using the confidential client is to use a client secret. What is the issue with using a public client?

Comment: @dreamcrash Actually I'm implementing RBAC in Keycloak (refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak), and it requires a confidential client to set up the authorization. I also prefer public clients but I haven't figured out how to use them in that case.

Comment: Can your client securely store a password so that nobody but the client has access to it?

Comment: @sventorben yep

Comment: Why not simply using the client_secret then?