# Resource vs Permission while authorizing user to a resource in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to authorize users to a resource in keycloak using **resource-based permission**.

using [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_obtaining_permissions) documentation, I can make an API call to keycloak to know whether a particular user is authorized to access a particular resource or not.

Now to my question, if I am authorizing a resource, why am I required to pass **permission** in this API call?

```
curl -X POST \
   http://${host}:${port}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
   --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
   --data "audience={resource_server_client_id}" \
   --data "permission=Resource A#Scope A" \
   --data "permission=Resource B#Scope B"
```

to my surprise, it's actually resource that is being passed (Resource A#ScopeA and ResourceB#ScopeB) into the **permission**. Have I misunderstood keycloak's terms? If I have understood terms correctly then shouldn't it be **resources** or **scopes** in the API request body instead of **permission**?

I was expecting the API to ask for resource name instead of asking **permission** and expecting resource name in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources, scopes, permissions and policies in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak)

Comment: naah! I checked it already. My question is around what **permission** means in the API request body.